# Flutter onChange executed twice

Tags: android, flutter

I have a text field, which has the onChange property, when it detects that the text has a \ n execute a function, the problem is that this function is executed twice, it should be mentioned, that in that function, I clean the text of the TextController.

```
TextField(
  maxLines: null,
  controller: codigoController,
  autofocus: true,
  onChanged: (text) {
    if (text.contains('\n')) {
      test();
    }
  },
),
```

```
 _test() {
    print("hello");
    codigoController.clear();
  }
```

Comment: what is your expectation ? do you need that _test method only executed once?

Comment: I need this function to be executed only once since a call to an api actually goes into it, which makes an insert in the database, so if it is executed twice it will generate duplicate records in the DB

Comment: okay. can it be achieved by using onSubmitted not by onChanged? I assume you want to capture 'Enter' button clicks..

Comment: I already tried what you mentioned, but it doesn't work in my case. The text that goes inside the textfield comes from a bar code reader, when I scan a code on the input, it writes the code + the \ n, which is when I need to execute the function

Comment: i have created app with your code snippet and it's working fine.

Comment: Maybe the barcode scanner triggers this behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the solution is to use `listener` on `TextController`

### 1. Add Listener

we can add listener at the first time Screen is rendered. Later we need to dispose it as stated by [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input#1-create-a-texteditingcontroller)

```dart
class _AutoCallApiState extends State<AutoCallApi> {
  TextEditingController codigoController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    codigoController.addListener(changesOnField);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    codigoController.dispose(); // release unused memory in RAM
    super.dispose();
  }
```

### 2. Handle changes and API Call

```dart
  Future callApi(String textToSent) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    print("Received OK from API");
    codigoController.clear();
  }

  void changesOnField() {
    print("Changes Called");
    String text = codigoController.text;

    if (text.isNotEmpty) {
      print('$text');
      if (text.contains('\n')) {
        callApi(text);
      }
    }
  }
```

### 3. Demo

[image: API only called once]

#### callApi method only called once

Note : you may see at the demo, it only prints "Saved data to API" once

### 4. Full Repo

You may look into this repo and build it locally. [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_text_field_control/blob/master/lib/b_screen/auto_call_api.dart)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but i get the same behavior.
I've noticed that when I call codigoController.clear () is when it runs twice, without it the code runs once

Comment: it's weird. Can you share the source ? I added some demo and repo link

Comment: Thank you !! finally this line did the magic: await Future.delayed (Duration (seconds: 3));
You saved my night :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((it) => {_controller.clear()});
```